# how to delete all files in a folder, but not the folder itself?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I try to delete all files including subdirectories in a folder:

```
NSFileManager *deleteMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path = @"~/test/";
[deleteMgr removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
```

And it deletes everything including the folder itself.
But what I expect is an empty folder. 
Could anyone please help me what did I do wrong?

Really thanks your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call [contentsOfDirectoryAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) on the directory in question, and then use removeItemAtPath on all of the paths it returns.