# How to delete all files in a folder, but not delete the folder using NIX standard libraries?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I am trying to create a program that deletes the contents of the /tmp folder, I am using C/C++ on linux.

```
system("exec rm -r /tmp")
```

deletes everything in the folder but it deletes the folder too which I dont want.

Is there any way to do this by some sort of bash script, called via `system()`; or is there a direct way i can do this in C/C++?

My question is similar to this one, but im not on OS X... [how to delete all files in a folder, but not the folder itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066067/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself)

Comment: `rm -r /tmp/*` will delete the contents of the folder.

Comment: If you want to invest in the future, you could use `boost::filesystem` to iterate through and delete each.

Comment: @AusCBloke: Uhm... that will delete all *visible* files in the folder (i.e. those that `*` expands to), but will not delete any file starting with `.`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oh yeah, good point.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: On a side note could deleting the contents of /tmp harm anything?

Comment: @gjj: It depends on what contents there are. Also consider that not all files there might be yours, that there might be files needed by running processes (named pipes, for example)... I would avoid deleting `/tmp` in general, but if you are in a controlled environment (embedded system) you probably know better than anyone what files are there...

Comment: If they're not your files, you probably won't have access to delete them, unless this command's being run as root.

Comment: Yes, it can harm. Many programs do assume that the folder exists. So deleting it and creating it again causes a race condition and might crash other programs. Don't do that.

Comment: @FindingNemo2ishappening. Please observe that any call to System is not safe: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C/C++, you could do:

```
system("exec rm -r /tmp/*")
```

In Bash, you could do:

```
rm -r /tmp/*
```

This will delete everything inside /tmp, but not /tmp itself.

Comment: Uhm... that will delete all visible files in the folder (i.e. those that * expands to), but will not delete any file starting with .

Comment: Any call to "system" from C is not safe. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132

Comment: @jackb: I agree. However (since you downvoted) keep in mind that the OP *did* ask, "...Is there any way to do this by some sort of bash script, called via system..."

Comment: @jackb: I agree that `system` is bad, but my answer was just expanding on the OP's question, which clearly was in the context of using `system`.  You should post your point as feedback to the original the question.

Comment: No excuse, other users provided a more correct answer. I upvoted one of those answers. I'm pretty sure you'll be more careful next time.

Comment: system("exec rm ./Blurred/*"); for me in linux is working.

Answer (score 54):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    // These are data types defined in the "dirent" header
    DIR *theFolder = opendir("path/of/folder");
    struct dirent *next_file;
    char filepath[256];

    while ( (next_file = readdir(theFolder)) != NULL )
    {
        // build the path for each file in the folder
        sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", "path/of/folder", next_file->d_name);
        remove(filepath);
    }
    closedir(theFolder);
    return 0;
}
```

You don't want to spawn a new shell via `system()` or something like that - that's a lot of overhead to do something very simple and it makes unnecessary assumptions (and dependencies) about what's available on the system.

Comment: Uhm... an answer that actually works for hidden files and does not require a shell! +1 (Although on the other side it will not delete directories recursively, and does not handle errors...)

Comment: you probably want to set `if (0==strcmp(next_file->d_name, ".") ||
                0==strcmp(next_file->d_name, ".."))
            {
                continue;
            }` at the beginning of the while statement if you don't want to delete the files "." and ".."

Answer (score 3):

by using use the wildcard `*` character you can delete all the files with any type of extension.

`system("exec rm -r /tmp/*")`

Comment: Uhm... that will delete all visible files in the folder (i.e. those that * expands to), but will not delete any file starting with .

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
system("exec find /tmp -mindepth 1 -exec rm {} ';'");
```

Comment: Uhm... that will delete all visible files in the folder (i.e. those that * expands to), but will not delete any file starting with .

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas you are right. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Any call to System is not safe https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ you can use (including hidden directories):

```
system("rm -r /tmp/* /tmp/.*");
system("find /tmp -mindepth 1 -delete");
```

But what if 'rm' or 'find' utilities are not availabe to sh?, better go 'ftw' and 'remove':

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>

static int remove_cb(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeFlag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    if (ftwbuf->level)
        remove(fpath);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    nftw("./dir", remove_cb,  10, FTW_DEPTH);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is very old question, but building on Demitri's great answer I created a function that will recursively delete files in subfolders if desired

It also does **some** error handling, in that it passes back errno. The function header is written for parsing by doxygen. This function works in the simple example cases I used, and deletes hidden folders and hidden files.

I hope this helps someone else in the future

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define SUCCESS_STAT 0

/**
 * checks if a specific directory exists
 * @param dir_path the path to check
 * @return if the path exists
 */
bool dirExists(std::string dir_path)
{
    struct stat sb;

    if (stat(dir_path.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * deletes all the files in a folder (but not the folder itself). optionally
 * this can traverse subfolders and delete all contents when recursive is true
 * @param dirpath the directory to delete the contents of (can be full or
 * relative path)
 * @param recursive true = delete all files/folders in all subfolders
 *                  false = delete only files in toplevel dir
 * @return SUCCESS_STAT on success
 *         errno on failure, values can be from unlink or rmdir
 * @note this does NOT delete the named directory, only its contents
 */
int DeleteFilesInDirectory(std::string dirpath, bool recursive)
{
    if (dirpath.empty())
        return SUCCESS_STAT;

    DIR *theFolder = opendir(dirpath.c_str());
    struct dirent *next_file;
    char filepath[1024];
    int ret_val;

    if (theFolder == NULL)
        return errno;

    while ( (next_file = readdir(theFolder)) != NULL )
    {
        // build the path for each file in the folder
        sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", dirpath.c_str(), next_file->d_name);

        //we don't want to process the pointer to "this" or "parent" directory
        if ((strcmp(next_file->d_name,"..") == 0) ||
            (strcmp(next_file->d_name,"." ) == 0) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        //dirExists will check if the "filepath" is a directory
        if (dirExists(filepath))
        {
            if (!recursive)
                //if we aren't recursively deleting in subfolders, skip this dir
                 continue;

            ret_val = DeleteFilesInDirectory(filepath, recursive);

            if (ret_val != SUCCESS_STAT)
            {
                closedir(theFolder);
                return ret_val;
            }
        }

        ret_val = remove(filepath);
        //ENOENT occurs when i folder is empty, or is a dangling link, in
        //which case we will say it was a success because the file is gone
        if (ret_val != SUCCESS_STAT && ret_val != ENOENT)
        {
            closedir(theFolder);
            return ret_val;
        }

    }

    closedir(theFolder);

    return SUCCESS_STAT;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From C++17 onwards you can use [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem). The code below will use [directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to list all the files and subdirectories in a directory and call [remove_all](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) to delete them:

```
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void delete_dir_content(const fs::path& dir_path) {
    for (auto& path: fs::directory_iterator(dir_path)) {
        fs::remove_all(path);
    }
}
```

Note that this will throw a `filesystem_error` exception on underlying OS API errors. You can avoid this with:

```
void delete_dir_content(const fs::path& dir_path) {
    for (auto& path: fs::directory_iterator(dir_path)) {
        std::error_code err;
        std::uintmax_t n = fs::remove_all(path, err);
        if (static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(-1) == n) {
            std::cout << "Failed to remove_all(" << path << ") with error: " << err.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). First, make a pass to collect the set of file paths to remove. Then use `unlink` (for non-directories) and [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) in a second pass