# How to remove directory name with special characters and directories with env variable name on UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, special-characters

I did a search in this repository and I didn't find any similar questions or may be my search was incorrect.

I have this problem in my clients environment, a custom application is creating directories with an environmental variable "$SRCDIR" and "$HOME" and the dir's where these are created , itself is the HOME dir path. if I say `rm -rf $HOME` then all the files and subdir's under $HOME which is current directory will be deleted . How do I delete these unwanted directories.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 grp domain users 418051450 Apr 18 18:09 $SRCDIR
-rw-r--r--  1 grp domain users 418051450 Apr 18 18:09 $HOME
```

Also some directories are junk characters as below example.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 grp domain users  0 Feb  7  2106 ??????w?O???*????_6??t??Ó¡?>?tP??Ñ?|?C
```

How do I delete them ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the junk names, it would be easiest to construct a wildcard that would catch only them. Select a *readable* portion of the name (e.g. the `_6` substring) and wrap it in asterisks. First try it out:

```
ls *_6*
```

If it lists *only* the junk name, proceed to delete it:

```
rm *_6*
```

If it lists other names as well, try to make the wildcard more specific, using other readable characters in the name:

```
ls *w*_6*tP*N*x*
```

Proceed until you've found a wildcard that would match only unwanted files.

Comment: @dicaprio feel free to accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: @lazz, I can accept your comments as answer, however this solves partly. The first and most important problem was how to remove directories with '$HOME'. $HOME is an env variable which points to the directories having many sub directories.

Comment: You already have that answered by @PavanManjunath. I'm not going to just copy his answer into mine. Feel free to accept either mine or his answer.

Comment: @dicaprio In what way does it not solve your problem? What error does `rm` throw?

Comment: I've got an empty with name `-P`,  neither of `rmdir \-P` nor `rmdir *P` worked. Finally, `rmdir -- -P` did the trick. `--` tells `rmdir` to treat the following `-P` as normal file name.

Answer (score 18):

Determine inode numbers of necessary files/folders:

```
# ls -ila 
14549980 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root       4096 Mar  5 20:45 ">?<
```

And pipeline it to `rm`:

```
find . -inum 14549980  -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer: in opposite to the accepted answer, it does not assume that the junk folder has any readable/writable char in it! Plus the answer uses the `-i` switch for interactive remove: this is far better than the bare `rm` suggested by the accepted answer. A perfect one-liner!

Answer (score 12):

if you create a directory like --rw-r-r--. to delete this file do the following

`rm -rf ./--rw-r-r--`

Comment: UNIX command rm(1) will consider everything after "--" not an option. So you could also remove that directory by issuing: rm -fr -- --rw-r-r--

Comment: This is a much better answer than the wildcard one.

Answer (score 4):

try zsh shell in linux

```
[root@rhel5-8 ~]# zsh
[root@rhel5-8]~
```

then use tab completion to remove that directory.

or if using bash

```
[root@rhel5-8 ~]# cd "??????w?O???*????_6??t??Ó¡?>?tP??Ñ?|?C???????>?Ì¤-???y?X???N?x??H?????Ð§)?n?5‌​??{@?~]?"
```

to get into that directory

Comment: this part is already done. How to remove directory with name like $HOME.

Comment: This works great. I found a directory named ? Bash would not remove it but zsh did

Answer (score 3):

Just escape the dollar symbol. Try like this-

```
rm -rf \$HOME
```

Same with even the `?` symbol.

Comment: I tried ` rm \?` and this is what it says. `rm: cannot remove `?': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Does `ls -al` show up `?` as a file? By the error, I can see that `rm` indeed is recognizing `?` as a file but is not able to find it.

Comment: This is the file name when I see ,`??????w?O???*????_6??t??Ó¡?>?tP??Ñ?|?C?????(??>?Ì¤-???y?X???N?x??H?????Ð§)?n?5??{@?~]??Z??o??????*`.

Comment: :) Unfortunately you need to escape all the special characters. Not just the first `?`. If tab completion is supported in your shell, then you are spared of the hard work!

Comment: I suspect the question marks are actually characters that are undisplayable in the encoding of the terminal, and not actual question marks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try rm -rf '$HOME' '$SRCDIR' , as the single quotes would prevent the expansion of the shell variables. tried with bash and ksh.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a **c** program to avoid shell/escape problems. Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007494/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-folder-but-not-delete-the-folder-c-linux).

Comment: I dont think this would help.

Comment: I went through all the answers , doesn't the directory $PINHOME get expanded in this case ?

Comment: It should not, for example when i do: os.listdir('$USER') it tries for find folder called '$USER'.
So in your case it's easy to do something like:

     import shutil
     shutil.rmtree('/folder_name')

Answer (score 0):

Alternative inode method:

`ls -ila`

Note the inode number e.g. 1234567

`rm -r $(find -inum 1234567)`